# How to pass input value from the form which is not part of any model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, forms

In razor view I have a form:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Person</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

etc.  for long time,but I want to pass values from these below to controller:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="FetchDate" name="FetchDate" type="date">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="FetchTime" name="FetchTime" type="time">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 200px; font-weight: bold;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

---

`Submit(type="submit)` button invokes `POST` edit action in `Person` controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName")] Person person) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(person);
    }
```

We can see that the only parameter is `Person person`, but inside the form I added two fields which have nothing in common with a Person but I also would like to pass values from them to POST `Edit` by submit button:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" >If you want this client to be fetched to you later, fullfil the data.</label>
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="FetchDate" name="FetchDate" type="date">
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="FetchTime" name="FetchTime" type="time">
</div>
```

**Question:** How to pass values to controller's POST `Edit` action which are not part of any model from my Razor view(above)?

---

I tried this and time is null or empty string(didn't check yet):

[HttpPost]

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName")] Person person, [Bind(Include="FetchTime")] String time) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Time " + time);
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(person);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName")] Person person, string FetchDate, string FetchTime) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(person);
}
```

Comment: This worked. Can I somehow use `DateTime` parameter instead of string?

Comment: It was smart enough to bind it to `DateTime`.

Comment: actually it is not that smart. Please see Turkey Test. Other than that, it automagically binds using specified type.

Comment: yes you can, this link explain how to do that http://www.stefanprodan.com/2011/05/send-date-time-objects-with-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: @edokan Ok, I am checking. Do you know why my solution on the bottom of OP didn't work?

Comment: @BayuAlvian It binded it without jquery I just wrote `DateTime` instead of `string` in parameter type. `DateTime? FetchDate, DateTime? FetchTime` to be exact.

Comment: @Yoda, I have no idea. I've never used `Bind` attribute. I just use same variable name as post field name.

Comment: @Yoda, The reason your edit in the OP does not work is because your parameter is named `time` but you `input` has the name `FetchDate` - they must match in order to bind.